# Page Load Affected by iframe

Tags: wordpress, iframe, scroll

I built a WordPress plugin for my company's customers and one of the options uses an `iframe`. A customer pointed out an interesting issue to me. When the page loads, it doesn't load at the top but loads just above the `iframe` (please see: http://salondshayn.com/wp/staff/jude-hair-stylist-hairdresser-scottsdale/). The same thing happens on my test site, and in all browsers I've tested (i.e., chrome and firefox).

I've narrowed it down to the `iframe`, but it may also have something to do with the way WordPress treats iframes. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936259/how-to-prevent-page-from-scrolling-to-an-iframe-on-load) is similar, but the answer given is to set `display: none;` which doesn't work because I need the iframe's contents to display.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't understand *"it doesn't loads at the top but loads just above the `iframe`"*. Are you referring to loading order or some sort of z-index? When I visit the page, Chrome's console is reporting jQuery as `not found`...

Comment: @brasofilo, thanks for the comment. I'm not referring to either loading order or z-index. Sorry if that's not clear. When you visit that page, it's going to land you midway down the page, just above the top of the iframe, instead of at the top of the page. It shouldn't have anything to do with jQuery, as it doesn't work on other WordPress sites I've tried. The question linked in my question reports the same issue, but doesn't give a very good solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding (two weeks later) the answer to this question. I took it from Nate's answer here - [iframe on the page bottom: avoid automatic scroll of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6596668/iframe-on-the-page-bottom-avoid-automatic-scroll-of-the-page/7148477#7148477)

I used:

```
<iframe style="position: absolute; top: -9999em; visibility: hidden;" onload="this.style.position='static'; this.style.visibility='visible';" href="..."></iframe>
```

It seems to have completely eliminated the scrolling issue.

Here was Nate's quote:

> Here we're basically saying hiding the frame and moving it to a negative offset on the page vertically. When it does try to focus the element inside of the frame, it should scroll the page upward, then once loaded place the iframe back in it's intended position.

Answer (score 0):

Use the scrollTo function and put this bit of javascript at the end of your page.
I took this from [Scrolling an iframe with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192228/scrolling-an-iframe-with-javascript)

```
    var myIframe = document.getElementById('iframe');
    myIframe.onload = function () {
        myIframe.contentWindow.scrollTo(xcoord,ycoord);
    }
```

If jQuery is involved, you can use this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            window.scrollTo(0,0);
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately this hasn't solved the problem, but it's put me in the right direction. Because this is a wordpress plugin I'll steer clear of jQuery. I tried it but there's too much variation between themes to make it work properly. When I use the javascript example I get _Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onload' of null_ Any idea what this could be? Also, I'm going to want to use a `document.scrollTo(0,0)` as I'm trying to scroll the document to the top, not the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

I'd extend the `scrollTo` issue pointed by @stevepowell2000 and suggest that you examine all the scripts of that `iframe`, much probably there's a `scrollTo` going on there.

I found this in the iframe source, but am [not sure](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/mobile-silentscroll) if it's related or not...

```
$("#siteMasterPage").live('pageshow', function(event) {
    var currentArea = $('#hidCurrentArea').val();
    if (currentArea === "business") {             
         setTimeout(function() {
            $.mobile.silentScroll(30);
         }, 10);
     }
});
```

If that's indeed the case, the matter would be how to prevent that, because applying a second scroll will probably look weird.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to look more into `$.mobile.silentScroll(30);` and see what I can find. From what I've seen that could be the issue.